# Help me evaluate a FIRST Robotics proposal?

Tags: discussion, scope

When a proposal for a new site nears the end of its "definition", it undergoes a review by the Community Team to see if it should move forward.

I need your help.

Below are the top "example questions" for proposal for FIRST Robotics competitions.

> #### [FIRST Robotics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87670/first-robotics?tab=votes#tab-top)
>
> *Proposed Q&A site for students and mentors from FRC, FTC and FLL teams*

I would like solicit thoughts from the Robotics community about whether this proposal is needed or if these questions would be a natural fit here.

***but…***

the actual task at hand is to evaluate this proposal on its merits. I'm trying to figure out **which questions (listed below) might be considered somewhat *specific* to a student robotics competition**, and which are just questions about "general robotics".

For example, questions about game-specific and FRC/FTC/FIRST-technology-specific hardware and tools are a good fit. The business and planning of competition issues are a good fit. Even robotics issues that are better answered in a competition-specific context are a good fit there.

Can you help me draw that line between competition-centric questions and a question about "general robotics" that don't really have a competition-specific context at all?

A list of questions or numbers or other comments are welcome. Thank you.

#### Top Example Questions

1. What are the equations used for a mecanum drive train?
2. How do I unit test my Java code without having a RoboRIO to run it on?
3. How do you communicate between the RoboRIO and a separate processor like a Raspberry Pi?
4. How can I organize my team to be more student-driven and less mentor-driven?
5. How do you access files on the RoboRIO? Like copying off a log file.
6. How can I retrieve data from FIRST's API to run OPR and related calculations on it?
7. How do you invert motor output without copying and pasting?
8. Where can I find WPILIB documentation?
9. Can older cRIOs run LabVIEW 2015 code?
10. For FLL, should I program the robot with the visual programming that it comes with, or use other programs?
11. When should I use PID?
12. What is a good solution for low-budget teams to custom-machine parts?
13. Is there a way to safely us python on the RoboRio? Pre-compilation, aggressive testing?
14. Is the driver station usable on Linux or OSX?
15. What features does the Talon SRX have that make it more (and less) useful than using a software PIDController?
16. Have any teams released code for controlling their swerve drives?
17. What are the side-effects of Swiss-cheesing your robot?
18. Where can I obtain a copy of the WPILib source?
19. How to decrease the weight of a load-bearing metal sheet?
20. I want to start volunteering in a specific role. How do I know what events to apply for, and what else should I start doing?
21. My robot's arm is a four-bar mechanism. How do I change it so that the gripper angle changes when the arm lifts up?
22. How to install WPILib and build tools for C++ on Ubuntu Linux?
23. How would I go about created an organized Code base that I could use in later years?
24. Is there a way to mix Java and C++ code on the RoboRio?
25. Will reversing the wires on the input or output of a jaguar break it?
26. How do I set up a stress analysis of my swerve module in Solidworks?
27. How can I perform a firmware upgrade for the PDP?
28. How can I select between multiple auto modes right before each match (preferably using the driverstation, without touching the robot)?
29. What alternatives to PID loops exist for effectively controlling a robot?
30. What is the best way to go about tuning a PID Controller?
31. What is the difference between "Bridge", "2.4 GHz" and "5Ghz" in the wireless bridge?
32. My team attracts lots of proto-engineers; how do I get students with other skills involved (e.g. PR, graphic arts, organizing)?
33. Is there a way to profile Java code on the RoboRio to find out where optimization could have the most benefit?
34. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using the different programming languages (Java, C++, Labview, RobotPy) [closed]
35. What is the different between a 14.5pa gear and a 20pa gear? Will gears with different pressure angles mesh together?
36. What aspects of hall of fame teams should we try to emulate to become a more competitve chairman's team?
37. Our controller keeps browning out just from driving around. How can we keep this from happening during competition?
38. In the FIRST Stronghold game, what is the function of having a drive team member in the spy box?
39. What is a PID controller?